# C# Read text file from resources rather than locally

Tags: c#, visual-studio, embedded-resource

I have tried multiple solutions on here but non of them I can get to work. All i want to do is read a text file from my resources folder rather than the actual local folder.

File name: `TextFile.txt`

"Local File" Code that works:

```
string[] spaces = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\a\\source\\repos\\a\\bin\\Debug\\TextFile.txt");
```

Current Code:

```
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceName = "TextFile.txt";

        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
        }

        string[] spaces = File.ReadAllLines(resourceName);
```

But I am getting the following error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: stream'

On this line:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
```

EDIT1 Tried this as per link:

```
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceName = "programname.TextFile.txt";

        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
        }

        string[] spaces = File.ReadAllLines(resourceName);
```

Same error

Comment: The resource name is not "TextFile.txt". See duplicate.

Comment: The problem is clearly in the line above it. It likely cannot find the manifest resource stream and is setting the variable `stream` to `null`.

Comment: tried `var resourceName = "programname.TextFile.txt";` still the same error

Comment: Or am i putting that in the wrong place? where should i put it?

Comment: Please, please read the duplicate properly. Evaluate all answers. First, validate whether your text file's build action is "Embedded Resource". Then, while debugging, call `assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();` to find its name.

Comment: I have tried, I'm not a C# dev im just filling in, triued multiple solutions, cant get it to work

Comment: It is set to embedded

Comment: And what does `assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` return at runtime?